# wordpress plugin jquery ajax call to function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**JQuery Code:**

```
jQuery("#dmhsc-form").on("submit", function () {
    var form = this;

    if (jQuery("input[name='url']", form).val() == "") {

        jQuery("div[id='results']", form).html('<div class="not-available">Please, Enter site address.</div>');
        return false;
    }

    var url = jQuery("input[name='url']", form).val();

    jQuery("div[id='results']", form).css('display', 'none');
    jQuery("div[id='results']", form).html('');
    jQuery("div[id='loading']", form).css('display', 'inline');

    var data = {
        'action': 'dmhsc_show',
        'url': url,
        'security': badnc_ajax.dmhsc_nonce
    };

    jQuery.post(badnc_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        var x = JSON.parse(response);
        if (x.status >= 0) {
            display = x.text;
        } else {
            display = "Error occured." + x;
        }
        jQuery("div[id='results']", form).css('display', 'block');
        jQuery("div[id='loading']", form).css('display', 'none');
        jQuery("div[id='results']", form).html(unescape(display));

    });
    return false;
});
```

**Plugin File**

```
function badnc_load_styles() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'badnc-script', plugins_url( 'script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery')); // script.js contains jquery code

wp_localize_script( 'badnc-script', 'badnc_ajax', array(
    'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'dmhsc_nonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'dmhsc_nonce' ))
);
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'badnc_load_styles' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'badnc_load_styles' );

function dmhsc_show() {

check_ajax_referer( 'dmhsc_nonce', 'security' );

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
   $url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['url']);

    if(!$url || !is_string($url) || ! preg_match('/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?$/i', $url)) {

      $result = array('status'=>0,'url'=>$url, 'text'=> '<div class="not-available">Please, Enter valid domain name.</div>');
      echo json_encode($result);

   } else {

/*$result = array('status'=>0, 'text'=> '<div class="not-available">Domain: '.$url.'</div>');  
echo json_encode($result);*/  //It display the message without calling to fucntion 

        check_https($url); //function call
   }    

}

die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_dmhsc_show','dmhsc_show');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dmhsc_show','dmhsc_show');

function check_https($host) {

    $result = array('status'=>0, 'text'=> '<div class="not-available">Domain: '.$host.'</div>');
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Problem**
I want to show "Domain: domain name" when I submit the form. Form contains url field and submit button.
but I don't know it is not displaying the message written in check_https() function.

I am also getting error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 74
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

If I display the message without calling to function check_https(), it works.

What should be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `var x = response` rather than `var x = JSON.parse(response);` ?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan I just tried it but the output is like: Error occured.{"status":0,"text":"
Domain: amazon.com<\/div>"}{"status":0,"text":"
Domain: <\/div>"}  Should stop using json_encode($result); ???

Comment: `$result = array('status'=>0, 'text'=> '<div class="not-available">Domain: '.$host.'</div>');
echo json_encode($result);` this code will return the same JSON response. What is the issue now?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan There is no issue when I modified the $result, it is working fine now. But Why it is not working with ` var x = JSON.parse(response); ` ???

Comment: Because the response was already a JSON object, so need to parse it, Also let me add this solution as answer so that it helps others too

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan  I am getting response in JSON from PHP then I am parsing it with JSON.parse(response) but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Yes, you are getting as `JSON` and your ajax request `dataType` is of `JSON` type which handle json response already, that is why no need to parse it again. If dataType is of `html` type then it is required.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Thanks. Got it.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan I have one query. Is it applies only for function calls??? I mean, It worked well when I have used JSON.parse(response) to display the message in directly in function dmhsc_show() Check the dmhsc_show() function code, I have commented the line which worked fine with JSON.parse(response)

Comment: `dmhsc_show()` isn't a php function, where you are sending response as json using `json_encode`? so where you were using `JSON.parse()` in it?

Comment: `dmhsc_show()` is a php function in my wordpress plugin file. I have commented the line. json_encode function creates json output and I am decoding it with `JSON.parse()` in Jquery. Look at the Jquery file.

Comment: ok, so if we will not send response as `JSON` object then it will definitely works fine because we need to parse it as object using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Simple, it depends upon how we are sending response, if we are sending json object from php then no need to parse it, if we are not encoding as json then we need to parse it